# Hasura 2.0, is there a way to use wildcards?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

Hello everyone I am having some issues with the way I used to query my data before updating to Hasura 2.0 (I am currently on Beta 1), so Before 2.0 if you sent a null value to a query it would act as a wildcard * , now that I updated to 2.0 all query variables must have non-null values, is there anyway I could get around this?

A small query will serve as an example:

```
query get_student_organization($authorId: Int, $gradeId: Int, $groupId: Int, $schoolId: Int) {
  validation: student_organization(where: {author_id: {_eq: $authorId}, escuela_id: {_eq: $schoolId}, grado_id: {_eq: $gradeId}, grupo_id: {_eq: $groupId}}) {
    id
  }
}
```

so if I send it with only

```
{"authorId": 5455}
```

I expect all other variables to act as wildcards.
Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply send your whole **where** object from your front-end!
That way you can simply omit the null variables at all. For this, you need to *tweak your query* a little bit.

```
query get_student_organization($wh_frontend: student_organization_bool_exp!) {
  validation: student_organization(where: $wh_frontedn) {
    id
  }
}
```

> In the variables section, add your non-null variables only:

```
{
  "where_fe": {
    "authorId": 5455
  }
}
```

so this time your haven't sent the **schoolId**, **groupId** and **gradeId** which serves your need for a **wild-card**.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much!